# To refresh a section of page

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

In joomla 2.5 , how to refresh the content of a page with the hyper link of the same page, with out refreshing the entire page .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to do so, there are plenty of useful howtos to get this done.

Also try this

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

you might want to see jQuery if you are not familiar with it already.